# Selenium WebDriver: For editing and deleting elements in a list, what are reason why I should always select the first element and vice versa

Tags: java, c#, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and I have the choice in my framework to select the first element in the list, or any element in the list to edit, remove, or any action that can be performed on the element for testing.

For example, I had three addresses in a list. Each address has a label. With each address, I am able to edit or delete that address. For the framework, I am able to either create a method that accepts no parameter, deleteAddress(),that will always delete the first address. Or I have the option to create a method in the framework that accepts a string parameter, deleteAddress(String label), that will search the list for that label to delete that particular address.

Is there pros on why I should always pick the first element and cons on why I shouldn't?

Comment: Question is not clear.Can you explain bit more

Comment: Sorry about that! Will edit right now. Up in 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some Pros to testing the first element in a list**:

- Element is typically easy/fast to find
- Element is less likely to not exist (i.e. all list elements may have to be deleted for the first element to not be found.)

**Some Cons to testing the first element in a list**:

- You can never be 100% sure of which list element you are testing
- You could end up altering something you shouldn't (e.g. editing/deleting User Admin privelages or other high level user permissions)
- The element you are testing may concurrently be tested/utilized by another member on your team
- You could end up deleting the entire list if your test runs repeatedly

In my experience, the first two cons raise enough concern that I always create and utilize an isolated test element, regardless of any pain required to interact with it. I want to have as much control over the element and its surroundings as possible, so I always know the precise state of the testing environment before/during/after each test. Also, if the element goes missing the test(s) fail and no other element is unexpectedly affected.